# Density of sets whose image is dense.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

This is probably easy, but I can't think of an answer. Assume $X$ is a Banach space and $A$ is a (not assumed closed) subspace of $X$. Let $T:X \to X$ be a bounded operator, which is also injective. If $T(A)$ is dense in $X$, does it follow that $A$ is dense in $X$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is injective, $A=T^{-1}(T(A))$, and by continuity, $$\overline A = \overline{T^{-1}(T(A))}=T^{-1}(\overline{T(A)})=\overline{T(A)}=X. $$ Hence, $A$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but isn't it that only $\overline{T^{-1}(T(A))}\subset T^{-1}(\overline{T(A)})$ is true ?

Comment: @Svetoslav $T^{-1}(T(A))=A$ so that inclusion yields $$\overline A=X\subset T^{-1}(\overline{T(A)}).$$

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. Try to explain it again ?

Comment: Since $T$ is continuous, $T^{-1}(M)$ is closed for any closed $M\subset X$. $\overline{T(A)}$ is closed, and so...

Comment: Sry, I don't see. Otherwise, if $T$ was an injective continuous operator from a Banach space $X$ to a Banach space $Y$, then I have a counterexample: Let $X$ be the space $H^1$, $Y=L^2$ and $T$ be the embedding operator $T: H^1\to L^2$. Then, if $A=C_0^\infty$, $T(A)$ is dense in $L^2$, but $C_0^\infty$ is not dense in $H^1$.

Comment: I do not see the inclusion $ T^{-1}(\overline{T(A)})\subset\overline{T^{-1}(T(A))}$

Comment: In the last identity in your answer: $T^{-1}(X)=X$ you assume that $T$ is onto $X$, which is not necessarily true. But if you assume surjectivity of $T$, then the statement can be seen by applying the open mapping theorem. If you do not have surjectivity, I don't think that the statement is true.

Comment: @Svetoslav Thank you for pointing out the flaw in my argument. The inclusion mentioned in your earlier comment follows from continuity and the penultimate equality in my revised solution follows from injectivity of $T$.